# Get formatted response in Json using two tables with CakePHP

Tags: json, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

Hello all i am newbie in cake php and struggling with formatting of JSON response the Cake PHP code is

```
    public function getdata() {
    $responce = array();
    $conn = ConnectionManager::get('default');
    $stmt = $conn->execute('select * from mst_categories a inner join mst_subcategories b on a.category_id=b.category_id');
    $turnos = $stmt->fetchAll('assoc');
    $responce['status'] = 1;
    $responce['message'] = 'Category Data';
    $responce['data'] = $turnos;
    $this->set(compact('responce'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['responce']);
}
```

as the result i am getting the JSON response as

```
{
"responce": {
    "status": 1,
    "message": "Category Data",
    "data": [
        {
            "category_id": "2",
            "category_name": "testing",
            "category_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\webroot\\img\\cat_images\\5311-3.jpg",
            "subcategory_id": "1",
            "subcategory_name": "New Subcategory",
            "subcategory_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\webroot\\img\\subcat_images\\8580-2820-3.jpg"
        },
        {
            "category_id": "2",
            "category_name": "testing",
            "category_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\webroot\\img\\cat_images\\5311-3.jpg",
            "subcategory_id": "2",
            "subcategory_name": "Testing",
            "subcategory_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\webroot\\img\\subcat_images\\1232-5311-3.jpg"
        }
    ]
  }
  }
```

While i want JSON output as described

```
[
 {
  "categoryId": 11,
   "categoryName": "cloths",
   "subCategoryData": [
    {
   "subCategoryName": "jeans",
   "subCategoryId": 0
    },
   {
     "subCategoryName": "shirt",
     "subCategoryId": 1
   }
 ]
},
{
  "categoryId": 12,
  "categoryName": "electronics",
   "subCategoryData": [
    {
    "subCategoryName": "TV",
   "subCategoryId": 2
   },
  {
   "subCategoryName": "fridge",
   "subCategoryId": 3
   }
 ]
 }
]
```

I am unable to know how can i achieve this type of response please help me in this query 
While calling

```
     $this->loadModel('MstCategories');
     $data= $this->MstSubcategories->find()->contain(['MstCategories']);
     $this->set(compact('data'));
     $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
```

i am getting response like this

```
  {
    "data": [
        {
        "subcategory_id": 1,
        "subcategory_name": "New Subcategory",
        "subcategory_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\update\\webroot\\\\img\\subcat_images\\8580-2820-3.jpg",
        "category_id": 2,
        "mst_category": {
            "category_id": 2,
            "category_name": "testing",
            "category_avtar": 
 "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\niattaupdate\\webroot\\\\img\\cat_images\\5311-3.jpg"
          }
      },
      {
          "subcategory_id": 2,
          "subcategory_name": "Testing",
          "subcategory_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\niattaupdate\\webroot\\\\img\\subcat_images\\1232-5311-3.jpg",
         "category_id": 2,
        "mst_category": {
            "category_id": 2,
            "category_name": "testing",
            "category_avtar": "C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\niattaupdate\\webroot\\\\img\\cat_images\\5311-3.jpg"
         }
     }
 ]
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: @ndm i dont think that is duplicate question because the link of the question that you given contain only one table but i have two tables

Comment: It wasn't too obvious on the first glance, given that you don't use the same data, fields/columns, and the indentation is pretty off too... but yeah, it's not an exact duplicate, it covers only one part - sorry. Why don't you use the ORM, which would give you the data in a properly nested fashion? And why do you need to rename/reformat the columns/fields?

Comment: I do not need rename or reformate i just given an example that how i want the o/p means i want for each category it will display all subcategiry and so on

Comment: @ndm how i get these responses via ORM can you give example for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to execute SQL command. If you have baked the models, you can try below code

```
public function getdata()
{
    // if in controller other than MstCategoriesController
    $this->loadModel('MstCategories');

    $data = $this->MstCategories->find()
        ->contain([
            'MstSubcategories'
        ]);

    $this->set(compact('data'));
    $this->set('_serialize', ['data']);
}
```

Comment: thanks for reply but while using this code i am not getting proper formatted response as i want subcategories under cagegory but this loc gives me categories under subcategory

Comment: Can you share the response you are getting?

Comment: See my query, it is far different from yours.

Comment: yup i understand but it also far away from the response i expected

Comment: Did you try running my query? It can not give your categories inside subcategories. Notice the difference, you are finding from `Subcategories` and containing `Categories`, in my case it is opposite.

Comment: this gives me error of MstCategories is not associated with MstSubcategories

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169236/discussion-between-anuj-tbe-and-user1870546).